# Split large xml file with xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, split, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have this source xml file.

```
   <DATA>
    <DATASET>      
      <KE action="create">
         <A>USVa</A>
         <B>USVb</B>
         <C>USV10</C>             
      </KE>
      <KE>
       ....
      </KE>
    </DATASET>
   </DATA>
```

The element "KE" exists round about 30000 times. I want to create every 5000 "KE" a new XML file. In the case of 30000 KE-elements must be the result 6 separate xml files and the structure a copy of the source xml.

How I can realize this with XSLT 2.0? I'm using saxonhe9-5-1-3j. Many thanks ...

Comment: For this sort of scale XSLT 2.0 should be fine but if you were talking 300,000 or 3,000,000 occurrences then you might be better off using more of a streaming approach e.g. something StAX based (since you mention Saxon I guess you're working in Java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the XSLT 2.0 functionality `xsl:for-each-group` and the modulus of the position of `KE` elements. Then, generate output documents with the `xsl:result-document` element.

My sample XSLT code creates a new result-document for groups of 3 `KE` elements. Adjust this number to "5000" for your input XML.

**Stylesheet**

**1** Simplified the stylesheet, thanks to @Martin Honnen. **2** Edited again, suggested by @michael.hor257k.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DATA">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DATASET">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="KE" group-starting-with="KE[(position() -1)mod 3 = 0]">
     <xsl:variable name="file" select="concat('ke',position(),'.xml')"/>
     <xsl:result-document href="{$file}">
        <DATA>
           <DATASET>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </DATASET>
        </DATA>
     </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get the following output (I have numbered the `KE` elements for convenience, the stylesheet does not rely on the `n` attribute).

**Output: ke1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
 <DATASET>
  <KE n="1" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
  <KE n="2" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
  <KE n="3" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
 </DATASET>
</DATA>
```

**Output: ke2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
 <DATASET>
  <KE n="4" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
  <KE n="5" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
  <KE n="6" action="create">
     <A>USVa</A>
     <B>USVb</B>
     <C>USV10</C>
  </KE>
 </DATASET>
</DATA>
```

The other output documents look the same.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that with a modulus of 3, the first group has only 2 elements. So, with 5000 the first group only has 4999 elements.

Comment: I think you should replace the `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">..</xsl:for-each>` by `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Yes, that's a good improvement. I'll edit my post.

Comment: You should be using `(position() -1) mod 3`. That will eliminate the first group anomaly.

Comment: thanks @MathiasMüller, is there a way to avoid hard-coding the ancestor nodes (DATA, DATASET) in the stylesheet ?

Comment: @HuiWang Most likely, yes - depending on what you exactly you mean by avoiding to hardcode this. In any case, if you have a new question then please open a new question post.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MathiasMüller. I mean that DATA and DATASET are hardcoded in the following expression.  <DATA>
           <DATASET>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
           </DATASET>
        </DATA>

Comment: @HuiWang I know, but the question is: What does it mean to not hardcode those elements? But as I said, please ask a new question instead of placing comments below a quite old answer. Thanks! (You can always link to this older question for reference.)